# Creating Radio Buttons that Update based on an Input in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking to create a group of radio buttons in a shiny app that will update based on a user input.  Basically, the user will choose a question, and the corresponding answer choices will be the updated options for the radio buttons.  I'm having trouble getting the buttons to update.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Very sorry about the formatting, first time using this site.

So far, I have:

```
questions <- read.csv("~/Answers.csv")
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("numberchoice",label = "Choose an image", choices = c(1:6), 
 selected = 1)
,
imageOutput("image")
,
radioButtons("answerchoice","",choiceNames = c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
choiceValues = questions[3,2:6])

)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
answers <- read.csv("~Answers.csv")
output$image <- renderImage(list(src=
paste("~",
input$numberchoice,".png", sep = "")
,contentType = "image/png", alt = "Face"),deleteFile = FALSE)
updateRadioButtons(session,"answerchoice",choices = 
questions[input$numberchoice,2:5]


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is do `observe` input$numberchoice for changes and update the radioButtons after changes happened:

```
# observe input$numberchoice and update answer radioButtons accordingly
observeEvent(input$numberchoice, {
    updateRadioButtons(session,"answerchoice",choices = questions[input$numberchoice,2:5])
})
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid `observeEvent`, you can put the whole answer output in the server, so that it will update at every change of `input$numberchoice`:

#### UI:

```
uiOutput("answerchoice")
```

#### Server:

```
output$answerchoice <- renderUI({
    radioButtons("answerchoice", "", choiceNames = c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
                 choiceValues = questions[input$numberchoice,2:5])
})
```